# how to populate textboxes with values of datareader

Tags: c#, textbox

i have some textboxes. in first textbox i entered a vaue like empid. after the clicking a button which goes to database  and checks for the columns specified by me. 
i get that data in datareader.

from datareader i need to display the particular employ information in the remaining textboxes.

how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your datareader is called rdr, something like this would work:

```
while(rdr.Read())
{
   txtBox1.Text = rdr.Item["DBFieldName1"].ToString();
   txtBox2.Text = rdr.Item["DBFieldName2"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: if item property of datareader is not there, what should i have to do

Comment: There should be a similar method somewhere I'd thought in that case, what exact class is your datareader.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (dr.Read())
{                    
    string checkValue = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
    if (checkValue == myEmpIdTextbox.Text)
    {
        Texbox2.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
        Texbox3.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
    }
}
```

Works in C# - Visual Studio 2015.

The values in the brackets () next to `GetValue` indicate the column number, relative to your SQL `Select` query.

EXAMPLE:

`SELECT coloumn1, coloumn2, coloumn3 FROM table`

Then, in this case, Textbox3.Text will be made equal to the data in coloumn3, and Textbox2. Text to coloumn2, for that row where coloumn1 is equal to your value in your Empid textbox.